# Sencha touch 2 list inside a panel

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

Have a pretty common task to do where I need a search form above a list to display the results, the problem is that the list is not showing the results, the store and the proxy work correctly because when I use firebug to locate the list items the list always have height of 0px.

I have already searched and the common ways to workaround this is to use a fit layout, but using that on the parent panel makes all look small as if the width used was 10px.

I cant set a fixed height because I want the list to fill the remaining space, and neither the flex option cause that stretches the search form when I want that to use the default size of the buttons and input fields.

Here is the config Im using on the view

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.search.Search', {
extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype: 'search_view',
config:{
    items:[
        {
            fullscreen:true,
            scroll:false,
            xtype:'panel',
            title:'Search',
            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'searchfield',
                    name:'search',
                    label:'Search',
                },
                {
                    xtype:'container',
                    layout:'hbox',
                    width:'100%',
                    margin:'3 0 0 0',
                    defaults:{
                        flex:1
                    },
                    items:[
                        {
                            xtype:'selectfield',
                            options:[
                                {text:'Option 1', value:'opt1'},
                                {text:'Option 2', value:'opt2'}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            text:'Search',
                            action:'search'
                        }
                    ]   
                },
                {
                    xtype:'list',
                    itemTpl:['{title}'],
                    onItemDisclosure:true,
                    plugins:[
                        { xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging' }
                    ]
                }

            ]
        },
    ],      
}
});
```

This image describes what Im trying to achieve, I took this screenshot by setting manually a height to the list container, as you can see it works the problem is that the list height doesn't fill the space below the form by default.

[image: goal]

Comment: `itemTpl:['{title}'],` ?.. why are you providing itemTpl an `array`

Comment: it can be an array according to the docs itemTpl : String/String[]/Ext.XTemplate when you have a multiline template makes it easier to edit.

Comment: What exactly are your trying to achieve through this code? Your code o/p also seems very much strange

Comment: I'v added an image to the question to better describe it, what part of the code seems strange to you, I've followed the examples on sencha docs as to how to define all this stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Your entire component structure seems odd. Any specific reason for this kind of structuring?

Comment: I don't see any stores in your list, have you tried to use a store and then just filtering the item name by the content of the search box using store filters? that's what I do to filter lists and it works pretty good.

Comment: @Roberto yeah I set the store later on a controller (the store used depends on some choices), the problem is not the store, the data is loaded correctly as you can see in the image. Thanks

Comment: Why a list within a panel within a dataview ?

Comment: @TDeBailleul there is no dataview, the hierarchy of the containers in this view is like this: NavigationView -> Panel -> List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing to solve this, it's more of a workaround since I had to change the layout to only have the list in it, and use toolbars for the search options, this way the toolbar controls only use the minimum height they need to draw themselves correctly.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.search.Search', {
extend:'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'search_view',
config:{
    fullscreen:true,
    layout:'card'
    items:[
        {
            xtype:'toolbar',
            docked:'top',
            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'searchfield',
                    name:'search',
                    flex:6
                },
                {
                    xtype:'button',
                    action:'search',
                    iconCls:'search',
                    iconMask:true,
                    ui:'simple',
                    flex:1
                }
                    ]
        },
        {
            xtype:'toolbar',
            docked:'top',
            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'selectfield',
                    flex:1,
                    options:[
                        {text:'Option 1', value:'opt1'},
                        {text:'Option 2', value:'opt2'}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
             xtype:'list',
             itemTpl:['{title}'],
             onItemDisclosure:true,
             plugins:[
                 { xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging' }
             ]

        },
        ],      
    }
});
```

As you can see I have two toolbars docked at the top, and the list filling the whole layout. Here is a screenshot of how it looks now.

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried setting your container layout to "fit"?, basically it will use all the remaining available height, here is a great guide on layouts for sencha touch: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/layouts right from the docs!

Answer (score 0):

Panel should have `vbox` layout, list should have `fit` layout and set `flex` option.

As seen if example bellow, if `flex` value is not set to a button, it should get default size.

From the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/layouts):

> Flexing means we divide the available area up based on the flex of
>   each child component...

Here is an example:

Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

```
config: {
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

  items: [
    {
      title: 'Welcome',
      iconCls: 'home',

      html: [
        "Some content"
      ].join("")
    },

    {
      title: "About",
      iconCls: 'star',
      layout: "vbox", // this card has vbox layout

      items: [{
        docked: 'top',
        xtype: 'titlebar',
        title: 'List'
      },

      {
        xtype: "list",
        layout: "fit", // take as much space as available
        flex: 1, // define flex
        data: [
          {name: 'Jamie Avins',  age: 100},
          {name: 'Rob Dougan',   age: 21},
          {name: 'Tommy Maintz', age: 24},
          {name: 'Jacky Nguyen', age: 24},
          {name: 'Ed Spencer',   age: 26}
        ],
        itemTpl: '{name} is {age} years old'
      },

      {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: "Button"
      }

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

});

And screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Note: I am learning Sencha Touch so I am not sure that written is correct.